# GCM on different devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I`m trying to implement GCM functionality, but it works in some devices but not in others.

```
 GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {

        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "xxxxxx");

    }
```

This is my code, when I start the app in nexus s it works fine and the app calls GCMBaseIntentService normally after GCMRegistrar.register(this, "xxxxxx");
But when I run the app in Samsung SII it calls GCMRegistrar.register(this, "xxxxxx"); but never call GCMBaseIntentService, none of the methods. The same happens others.

Comment: Your Samsung SII is registered to GCM? Do you get regId for both of the devices? regId is blank because it's not registered yet.

Comment: Maybe those phones are rooted.. do you know if the phones are rooted and have custom rom?

Comment: Im trying to registe the phone to gcm and I dont receive a never receive a feedback from google server into GCMBaseIntentService. The phones arent rooted

Comment: on logcat I receive the message: "Registering app 'mypackage' of senders 'sender_id'" but nothing happens

Comment: Do you have any Google account enabled in your Samsung SII?

Comment: yeap there is a google account enabled

Comment: the devices is running on android 2.3, but this probably isnt a problem, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the catlog, see if regid is successfully obtained.

Refer to those error below: 
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#handling_reg

Most probably it is caused by:

```
W/GoogleLoginService(166): Device has no accounts: sending Intent {act=com.google.android.gsf.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_MISSING }
```

since some of the devices does not have google account sync in the device. If so, try go to setting and set up a google account.